# Singular Points in Different Areas of Mathematics

Tags: analysis

What is the relationship between singular points of algebraic curves (as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_point_of_a_curve) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_point_of_an_algebraic_variety)), singular points of ode's (as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_singular_point) or [here](http://www.math.ksu.edu/math240/math240.f10/book/chap4/regsing.php)) and singular points in complex analysis (as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_singularity#Complex_analysis) or [here](http://math.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/SingularityZeroPoleMod.html))? They seem like three completely distinct ideas, yet I'd wager that the last two definitions fall out of the Taylor expansions of $f(x,y,y')$ or $f(z)$, i.e. that they come out of the definition that allows for ideas like crunodes & acnodes & that theses ideas potentially relate to the other definitions - any thoughts?